# How to normalize two time series for comparison?

Tags: time-series, normalization

I have two time series a and b, which I want to compare. Due to their range difference I normalize them first.

```
a(i), b(i) are natural numbers for i=1,...,N
```

two different normalizations:

( mean and std_dev both refer to the whole time series )

1) `a'(i) := a(i) / mean( a )`

*goal*: mean( a' ) = 1

2) `a'(i) := [ a(i) - mean( a ) ] / std_dev( a )`

*goal*: usual normalization

what confuses me is how do the meanings after those transformations differ?

does the first transformation make any sense at all?

Comment: are your series stationary --i.e. is mean(a) constant over time?

Comment: no, the series' are highly volatile. there is nothing constant over time.

Comment: I believe that your series can jump all over the place, but have a (near) constant mean. That's why people detrend or difference time series.

Answer (score 3):

The first one will make two series indistinguishable, provided they are proportional to one another, i.e., $a_i = \lambda b_i$ for all $i$.

The second one will make two series indistinguishable, provided they are linear combinations of one another, i.e., $a_i = \lambda b_i + \mu$ for all $i$.

The first will set mean to one and the second will set mean to zero and variance to one; I don't think there is much to be said about the behavior of structurally different series under these normalizations.

Comment: the series are neither proportional nor linear combinations. They are individual time series driven by a similar basic force. So I end up with two different normalizations for one series. Which normalization does make more "sense" if I want to compare?

Comment: I'm just describing the normalizations in terms of their properties, if that makes sense. To compare, you would have to apply the same normalization to both time series. And which one to use depends solely on what you mean by "the same basic force". If you mean they are correlated, then apply the second normalization.

Comment: Hi, couldn't you index both series? Let's say the first observation in each series is 100. Then you have them on the same scale, and you can compare them.

Answer (score 1):

one thing i've found is how you will compare these two eventually, and how the normalized time series will affect the behavior of that comparison method. Let's say I have a set of original valued time series, and the values range from around 70 to 200. When I use your second normalization method, it has a mean of 0 and sd of 1. Even though the time series is exactly the same if you plot it, but notice that in the normalized time series, the values only range from -3 to 3. So what I found out is that, when I use k means clustering to cluster the original valued time series, the result is very good, around 88% accuracy. But the same clustering task on the new, normalized time series, has a lower accuracy of 66%. So to sum up, the different properties of the numbers before and after the normalization may affect the behavior of the algorithm that you're using to compare them. Beware.